# C++, static array, pointer, length

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

Can somebody explain to me why this code works?!!

I know A holds &A[0] and it is not a real pointer as if you cout<<&A you would get &A[0], but this result looks very strange to me.

```
int main()
{
    double A[] = {2.4, 1.2, 4.6, 3.04, 5.7};
    int len =  *(&A+1) - A; // Why is this 5?
    cout << "The array has " << len << " elements." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And why this code doesn't work? And how can you make it work?

```
void test(double B[])
{
  int len = *(&B+1) - B;
  cout << len << endl;

}
int main()
{
    double A[] = {2.4, 1.2, 4.6, 3.04, 5.7};
    test(A);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe `&A` has the type `double[5]*` in this case

Comment: or you could use std::vector :-)

Comment: You are the victim of a common misconception that `&A` and `&A[0]` are identical thing, while they are, in fact, not.

Comment: @pm100 it's a pity comments can't be downvoted. If somebody can't understand how pointers to arrays work in C++, using `std::vector` IS NOT a solution.

Comment: @SergeyA I totally disagree with you. I think pointers shouldn't even be mentioned when teaching C++ until teaching virtual inheritance. Until then teach using `std::vector` and standard library.

Comment: @SergeyA - it was a joke (see the smiley face at the end). It was based on the regular comment in c++ questions about arrays. The 99% answer is 'dont use arrays use std::vector'. Chill

Comment: Considering that there are two well-versed commenters here that claim the code causes UB, it sure is a good advise. I'd word it differently though: Find a cleaner solution (e.g. using `std::vector` or `std::array`)! But still, learning that `&A` is not the same as `&A[0]` is the most valuable info here.

Comment: To @user3112666, please don't change the direction of questions after they have been answered. In particular, your second question should go to a separate question here. That said, did you follow the discussion about the code causing UB?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. It was quite helpful

Comment: @bolov how can you use standard library without using pointers???

Comment: @SergeyA are you joking? The standard library uses iterators, not pointers.

Comment: @bolov, well, I guess your knowledge of standard library is lacking... Do you want me to show you examples of where standard library uses pointers, or you can take it is a homework upon yourself?

Comment: @SergeyA yes please do. And while you do that think about the context in which I said that. I was talking about teaching C++. My point is: pointers are an unnecessary complication to teach early on. You really are going to have a much better success teaching `std::vector` and `std::string` and standard library algorithms like `std::sort` and erase-remove idiom etc. than to teach C arrays with pointers from the start or god forbid classes with `char*` data members manually allocated with `new` in ctors. If you can provide a good reason to teach pointers early on I am interested to hear it.

Comment: @bolov like I said, you can't use standard library in full without understanding pointers. Easiest example which comes to mind: `stoi`. Takes pointers. It is also almost impossible to write any meaningful program without interoperation with operating system, which would require using pointers as well.

Comment: @SergeyA yes you most definitely can. I won't continue the argument. We disagree. Let's leave it at that.

Comment: @bolov you are free to disagree, but how would you use `stoi` without pointers?

Comment: I would simply not teach `stoi`. It's a lower level function. Just how I would not teach `mmap` (ok a bit of an extreme example, but I hope you see the point, although I think it should have been obvious from 2-3 posts earlier so ...).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression is parsed like this:

```
(*((&A) + 1)) - A
```

The probably vexing part is that for some (but not all!) parts of this expression, the array decays to a pointer to the first element. So, let's unwrap this:

1. First thing is taking the address of the array, which gives you a pointer to an array of five elements.
2. Then, the pointer is incremented (`+ 1`), which gives the address immediately following the array.
3. Third, the pointer is dereferenced, which yields a reference to an array of five elements.
4. Last, the array is subtracted. It is only here that the two operands actually decay to a pointer to their first elements. The two are the length of the array apart, which gives the number of elements as distance.

Comment: isn't the deference technically UB?

Comment: With the caveat that `*(&A + 1)` is UB.

Comment: I don't actually know. I know that using the address (*not* accessing the memory) of an element after the end of an array is allowed, to form "past the end" iterators. Since the memory isn't read here, I could imagine it being valid.

Comment: Yes, it's UB. Forming a one-past-the-end pointer is one thing; dereferencing it is quite another. Those who claim that `&*`identity saves the day are wrong.

Comment: If you can provide a reference for that, @LightnessRacesinOrbit, make it an answer. You would get my upvote for it.

Answer (score 4):

`&A` takes the address of `A` itself.  The type of `A` is `double[5]`.

When you take the address of `A` itself and increment that pointer by 1, you are incrementing it by `sizeof(double[5])` bytes.  So now you have a pointer to the address following the `A` array.

When you dereference that pointer, you have a reference to the next `double[5]` array following `A`, which is effectively also a `double*` pointer to the address of `A[5]`.

You are then subtracting the address of `A[0]` (an array decays into a pointer to its first element), and standard pointer arithmetic gives you 5 elements:

```
&A[5] - &A[0] = 5
```